# Right way to define interface type on class that contains a member of said interface type

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I'm trying to figure out how to create an instance of a class which has a member that is an interface and somehow indicate that I want that member of that instance to be of certain class that implements the interface. I've been trying to use generics and other tricks but it's not working

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class BaseClass<TGeneric> where TGeneric : Interface
    {
        public TGeneric member;

        public BaseClass() {
            member = new Implementation1(); //Getting an error here :(
        }
    }

    public interface Interface
    {
        void sayHello();
    }

    public class Implementation1 : Interface
    {
        public void sayHello() {
            Console.WriteLine("interface 1");
        }
    }

    public class Implementation2 : Interface
    {
        public void sayHello() {
            Console.WriteLine("interface 2");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            BaseClass<Implementation1> b = new BaseClass<Implementation1>();
            b.member.sayHello();
            Console.Read();
        }

    }
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine if instead you defined b like so:

`BaseClass<Implementation2> b = new BaseClass<Implementation2>();`

Then obviously `member = new Implementation1();` will fail because you're trying to assign an instance of Implementation1, to a member which is type Implementation2.

Instead you need to create a TGeneric and assign it to member:

`member = new TGeneric();`

This also requires you to change the base class signature to:

`public class BaseClass<TGeneric> where TGeneric : Interface, new()`

Alternatively you could have member be of type `Interface`, rather than `TGeneric` so the type is no longer concrete.

Comment: I'd never have imagined that adding "new()" to the class' signature would have been the answer... thanks so much!

Comment: You need it to guarantee to the compiler that your TGeneric class will have an empty constructor. No worries.